# Numberlist com VisuAlg

Tags: visualg, portugol

Problema com esse algoritmo no visualg
O codigo está fazendo loop infinito
"Numberlist"

```
// Função :

// Autor :

// Data : 09/02/2016

// Seção de Declarações 

var

a1,b1,c1:inteiro

inicio

// Seção de Comandos 



    para a1 de 0 ate 9 faca

    para b1 de 0 ate 9 faca

    para c1 de 0 ate 9 faca



a1 := 0

b1 := 0

c1 := 0


escreva

("a1","b1","c1")

    fimpara

    fimpara

    fimpara


 fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Olá Joás. Reabri a pergunta, mas o formato "ache o erro no código" eu ainda acho meio estranho – está mais pra desafio que pergunta. Se esse código gera uma mensagem de erro, ou gera uma saída incorreta, citar isso seria um caminho mais interessante. Por exemplo: "Meu algoritmo deveria produzir uma saída *assim*, mas está gerando uma saída *assado*. O que está acontecendo?". Nem precisa editar esta (ainda mais porque ela teve boa aceitação), mas considere isso para suas próximas postagens. E bem-vindo ao site :)

Comment: obrigado pelo feedback @bfavaretto !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei!
1°
As variaveis têm valores declarado dentro do " para ate faca".
Em qualquer codigo isto faz com o que o loop seja infinito.

2°
Em "escreva(..)" as variaveis estam escritas entre aspas. O que caracteriza as variaveis como texto, contrariando a declaraçao de variaveis como "inteiro"

O codigo da forma correta seria desta forma

```
// Função : 

// Autor :

 // Data : 09/02/2016 

// Seção de Declarações 

var 

a1,b1,c1:inteiro

 inicio 

// Seção de Comandos


 a1 := 0

 b1 := 0 

c1 := 0 

 para a1 de 0 ate 9 faca

 para b1 de 0 ate 9 faca 

para c1 de 0 ate 9 faca


escreva

(a1,b1,c1)

fimpara

 fimpara 

fimpara 

fimalgoritmo
```

:v

Comment: Reformulei o post e a resposta.